# Can I return a list of keys for each value to map records into a map?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I wasn't sure about the title but what I want is the following:

The table `shop_offer_time_period` tells how low an offer is valid. This is done by `valid_from_day` and `valid_until_day` as well as by `day_of_week_id`.

Such a time period is always valid for n * 7 days. This means that if I am fetching from `2000-01-01` until `3000-01-01` I might get the same `shop_offer` multiple times if `shop_offer_time_period` says for example that an offer is valid *every monday* from *2015-01-01* until *2018-01-01*.

This is why I want to fetch this in a map like this

```
// ..
"2015-01-05": [{"offer_id":1}],
"2015-01-06": [{"offer_id":2}, {"offer_id":3}],
"2015-01-07": [],
"2015-01-08": [],
"2015-01-09": [],
"2015-01-10": [],
"2015-01-11": [],
"2015-01-12": [{"offer_id":1}],
"2015-01-13": [{"offer_id":2}, {"offer_id":3}],
// ..
```

I'd like to know if I can provide a `RecordMapper` which returns a list of keys for a single record.

The following is an example how my fetch currently looks like. At the moment I am taking `fetchInto` and do the mapping elsewhere. However, if it is somehow possible, I'd like to do the mapping right here inside my repository.

```java
Table<?> asTable = this.ctx.select(
        SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.SHOP_OFFER_ID,
        SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.PRICE
        )
        .from(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD)
        .where(
                SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.SHOP_ID.eq(shopId)
                .and(

                    // Contained
                    SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.VALID_FROM_DAY.greaterOrEqual(fromDay)
                    .and(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.VALID_UNTIL_DAY.lessOrEqual(toDay))

                    // Overlapping from left
                    .or(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.VALID_FROM_DAY.lt(fromDay)
                    .and(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.VALID_UNTIL_DAY.gt(fromDay))

                    // Overlapping from right
                    .or(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.VALID_FROM_DAY.lt(toDay)
                    .and(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.VALID_UNTIL_DAY.gt(toDay))))))

        .asTable("shopOfferTimePeriod");

List<ShopOfferDTO> fetchInto = this.ctx.select(
        SHOP_OFFER.ID,
        SHOP_OFFER.SHOP_ID,
        SHOP_OFFER.SHOP_TIMES_TYPE_ID,
        asTable.field(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.DAY_OF_WEEK_ID),
        asTable.field(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.PRICE)
        )
        .from(SHOP_OFFER)
        .join(asTable)
        .on(asTable.field(SHOP_OFFER_TIME_PERIOD.SHOP_OFFER_ID).eq(SHOP_OFFER.ID)
                .and(SHOP_OFFER.SHOP_TIMES_TYPE_ID.eq(offerType)))
        .fetchInto(ShopOfferDTO.class);
```

---

Please note that I am already fetching the result into my DTO instead of a generated record object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways how this question can be answered. Probably, you're looking for a SQL solution, but the way this question is currently phrased, this answer might do.

The most straightforward way would be to offer you these two alternatives of creating in-memory grouping in Java, after fetching the data from the database:

#### Using jOOQ API:

```
Map<Date, List<Integer>> result =
this.ctx.select(
    ...
)
.from(SHOP_OFFER).join(...)
.fetchGroups(SHOP_OFFER.DATE_COLUMN, SHOP_OFFER.ID);
```

(I'm assuming you have such a `DATE_COLUMN` here)

#### Using Java 8

jOOQ integrates seamlessly with Java 8's Stream API ([examples can be seen in this blog post](http://blog.jooq.org/2014/04/11/java-8-friday-no-more-need-for-orms/)), so the most powerful way to solve your problem would probably be to do it with Java 8 Streams:

```
Map<Date, List<Integer>> result =
this.ctx.select(
    ...
)
.from(SHOP_OFFER).join(...)
.fetch()
.stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        r -> r.getValue(SHOP_OFFER.DATE_COLUMN),
        Collectors.mapping(
            r -> r.getValue(SHOP_OFFER.ID),
            Collectors.toList()
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Luke! Thanks for you fast response! Should `r` be correctly inferred as `ShopOfferRecord`? For some reason `r` is just an `Object` if I apply this after `join(..).on(..)`.

Comment: `r` should be `Record` because you're getting a `Stream<Record>` after a join. But of course, if you already implemented the right POJO, that'll do as well... :)

Comment: I'll check that tomorrow but I think it was `Map<Object, List<Object>>` .. on the other hand Eclipse had some trouble with code completion inside the `Collectors` part.. maybe there went something else wrong.

Comment: Interesting. Well, the `Map` key and value types are inferred indirectly from `Field<T>`. If those fields are "plain SQL" fields, for instance, it may well be that `Object` is inferred. On the other hand, Eclipse used to have some bugs in that area, so perhaps you should upgrade to Mars.2...